# Do people use MinGW without MSYS

Tags: makefile, mingw, msys

I have a makefile that works in Windows using MinGW as well as on Linux. I want to tidy it up using some shell scripting in the recipe. But for that I need to add MSYS to my environment. 
I am not sure if the users of MinGW use MSYS always/often/rarely/never? 
Any feedback please.

Comment: The better alternative is to use https://cygwin.com/ instead of MSYS. I would drop MSYS/"standalone mingw" support at all in favor of Cygwin. I think that mingw is widely used outside of MSYS only as integrated part of some IDE, like Codeblocks or DevC++, i.e. not from handwritten makefiles

Comment: @igagis unfortunately don't have that option.